# html5lib error after update Dart SDK version 0.3.2.0_r17657

Tags: dart, dart-webui

When i run the build.dart of my Web Component, the out folder is not created and i receive this error:

```dart
SEVERE web/main.html: exception while reading file, original message:
 AsyncError: ''package:html5lib/dom.dart': Error: line 91 pos 51: type 'LinkedHashMap' is not loaded
  LinkedHashMap<dynamic, String> attributes = new LinkedHashMap();
malformed type used.'
Stack trace:
#0      Node.Node (package:html5lib/dom.dart:91:51)
#1      Document.Document (package:html5lib/dom.dart:313:16)
#2      TreeBuilder.reset (package:html5lib/src/treebuilder.dart:100:16)
#3      TreeBuilder.TreeBuilder (package:html5lib/src/treebuilder.dart:87:10)
#4      HtmlParser.HtmlParser (package:html5lib/parser.dart:148:38)
#5      parseHtml (package:web_ui/src/compiler.dart:34:16)
#6      Compiler._parseHtmlFile.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:web_ui/src/compiler.dart:165:28)
#7      time (package:web_ui/src/utils.dart:38:24)
#8      Compiler._time (package:web_ui/src/compiler.dart:297:16)
#9      Compiler._parseHtmlFile.<anonymous closure> (package:web_ui/src/compiler.dart:164:32)
#10     _ThenFuture._sendValue (dart:async:372:24)
```

Has anyone the same problem?

Update: thanks for answers. However, i run `pub update` and now if i run build.dart file the result is:

```dart
Uncaught Error: NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'innerHTML'
Receiver: Instance of 'Element'
Arguments: []
Stack Trace:
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch:1743:25)
#1      _ElementLoader.visitScriptElement (package:web_ui/src/analyzer.dart:879:16)
#2      _ElementLoader.visitElement (package:web_ui/src/analyzer.dart:770:40)
#3      TreeVisitor.visit (package:html5lib/dom_parsing.dart:208:50)
#4      TreeVisitor.visitChildren (package:html5lib/dom_parsing.dart:220:49)
#5      TreeVisitor.visitNodeFallback (package:html5lib/dom_parsing.dart:228:48)
#6      TreeVisitor.visitElement (package:html5lib/dom_parsing.dart:237:50)
#7      _ElementLoader.visitElement (package:web_ui/src/analyzer.dart:777:34)
#8      TreeVisitor.visit (package:html5lib/dom_parsing.dart:208:50)
#9      TreeVisitor.visitChildren (package:html5lib/dom_parsing.dart:220:49)
#10     TreeVisitor.visitNodeFallback (package:html5lib/dom_parsing.dart:228:48)
#11     TreeVisitor.visitElement (package:html5lib/dom_parsing.dart:237:50)
#12     _ElementLoader.visitElement (package:web_ui/src/analyzer.dart:777:34)
#13     TreeVisitor.visit (package:html5lib/dom_parsing.dart:208:50)
#14     TreeVisitor.visitChildren (package:html5lib/dom_parsing.dart:220:49)
#15     TreeVisitor.visitNodeFallback (package:html5lib/dom_parsing.dart:228:48)
#16     TreeVisitor.visitDocument (package:html5lib/dom_parsing.dart:230:52)
#17     TreeVisitor.visit (package:html5lib/dom_parsing.dart:212:52)
#18     analyzeDefinitions (package:web_ui/src/analyzer.dart:33:15)
#19     Compiler._parseAndDiscover.processHtmlFile.<anonymous closure>  (package:web_ui/src/compiler.dart:123:35)
#20     time (package:web_ui/src/utils.dart:38:24)
#21     Compiler._time (package:web_ui/src/compiler.dart:291:16)
#22     Compiler._parseAndDiscover.processHtmlFile (package:web_ui/src /compiler.dart:122:27)
#23     _ThenFuture._sendValue (dart:async:372:24)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just went through this. It's because the packages you have, haven't been updated. Make sure you are using latest versions of every package, and run `pub update`.

In my case, I was using an older version of `web-ui`, which used an older version of `html5lib` package. I updated `web-ui` and things worked.

And like Florian said in the other answer, it's caused by a class which has moved to another library.

Comment: Today I retry to run  `pub update` and now it's work fine. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1):

I recently moved 'LinkedHashMap' from dart:core into dart:collection.
The code you are showing still expects it in core.

Try to find an updated version of the html5lib package (maybe the mailing-list knows where you can download one).

Bob is currently working on versioning the dart-sdk in pub. So hopefully this shouldn't be such a problem in the future.